# kivy floatlayoutApp.x has an invalid format

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, kivy

i try to make an app that takes values from user and put them in a mysql database but when i click the button it gives me that error

```
floatlayoutApp.x has an invalid format (got <__main__.video object at 0x0000000007371BE0>)
```

i dont know what is the problem here so i didnt tried anything else 
here is my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column,Integer,String
import sqlalchemy
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')

eng = create_engine('mysql://root:mysql333@localhost:3306/mydb')

Session=sessionmaker(bind = eng)

session = Session()

base=declarative_base()

class video(base):
    __tablename__= 'videos_test'
    video_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    video_name=Column(String(100),index=True)
    video_url=Column(String(255))
base.metadata.create_all(eng)


class floatlayoutApp(FloatLayout):

    name=""
    url=""

    def create_instance(self,name,url):
        try:
            self.x=video(video_name=self.name,video_url=self.url)
            session.add(self.x)
            session.commit()
        except ValueError as err:
            print (err)



class YCEApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return floatlayoutApp()

YCE=YCEApp()
YCE.run()
```

and thats my kv.file code

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32

<FloatLayout>:
    id: YCE
    display: entry
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "image1.jpg"
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            font_size: 32
            multiline: False
            size_hint: .45, .2

        CustButton:
            size_hint: .45,.2
            text:"enter video name"
            background_color:1,1,1,1
            on_press: root.name = entry.text
        CustButton:
            text:"enter video url"
            size_hint: .45 , .2
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"top":1}
            on_press: root.url = entry.text
        CustButton:
            text:"create"
            size_hint: .45 , .2
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"top":1}
            on_press: root.create_instance(root.name,root.url)
```

i just dont know what is the issue and i think the issue is in the create instance method

Comment: `self.x=video(video_name=self.name,video_url=self.url)` FloatLayout has already an property x which is the position on the x achses. What are you trying to do here? What you are trying to assign does not comply with what it is expecting. It expects a value for the x achses.

Comment: what i am trying to do is to take the video_name and the video_url from the textinput and then create an instance ffrom the video class which is inherited from sqlalchemy declarative_base and by that way i can insert it in the table 'videos_test' by those methods  session.add(instance) session.commit() i hope that help to understant what im trying to do here

Comment: self.x is just already occupied. why don't you use sth like self.video?

Comment: oh sorry i didnt understand what u was talking about in the first comment but now i do and thank u that was really helpful it works now :)

Comment: I added it as an answer. :) Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FloatLayout.x is already a property referring to the position on the x-axis.
Add video to a new property. See https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.x

change

```
self.x=video(video_name=self.name,video_url=self.url)
```

to

```
self.video=video(video_name=self.name,video_url=self.url)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and it was because I was specifying the position in numpy's float64 dtype.  I needed to convert it to a native Python type (float):

For example,

```
lpos = np.array([50.0, 40.0])

# Convert lpos back from float64 to float
lpos = [lpos[0].item(), lpos[1].item()]

l = Label(text='hello', pos=lpos)
```